# Trying to Compute Portfolio standard deviation using numpy, getting an error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to calculate portfolio values like return, standard deviation for randomly generated portfolios. However, I get an error while calculating the standard deviation

Tried to convert the numpy array into matrix, but still does not work.

```
for i in range(no_of_portfolios):
            #Select random weights and normalize to set the sum to 1
            weights = np.array(np.random.random(no_of_assets))
            weights /= np.sum(weights)
            print("Weights are before reshaping",weights,np.shape(weights))
            np.reshape(weights,(3,1))
            print("Weights are after reshaping",weights,np.shape(weights))
            #Calculate the return and standard deviation for every step
            portfolio_return = np.sum(mean_returns * weights)            
            portfolio_std_dev = np.sqrt(np.dot(weights.T,np.dot(v_cov, weights)))

            #Store all the results in a defined array
            v_simulation_res[0,i] = portfolio_return
            v_simulation_res[1,i] = portfolio_std_dev

v_cov is [[ 0.04   -0.009  -0.01  ]
 [-0.009   0.0225 -0.009 ]
 [-0.01   -0.009   0.01  ]]
no_of_portfolios = 10
    no_of_assets = 3
    mean_returns = np.matrix([[0.3],[0.2],[0.1]])
    vol_arr = np.matrix([[0.2],[.15],[0.1]])
    rho_arr = np.matrix([[1,-0.3,-0.5],[-0.3,1,-0.6],[-0.5,-0.6,1]])
```

I am expecting to get one number for portfolio_std_dev ,for each combination of asset weights, i.e. 10 values(one for each row)

I am getting an error:

```
ValueError: shapes (3,) and (1,3) not aligned: 3 (dim 0) != 1 (dim 0)
```

it is probably because the weights array has the shape (3,0), but not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> np.reshape(weights,(3,1))
>   print("Weights are after reshaping",weights,np.shape(weights))

np.reshape returns the reshaped array. It doesn't change in place. So, I'm not sure what you're doing here but I'm guessing you missed the shape change? Assign to weights if you intended to change shape.